# Javax JCR Node getProperties and Titles

Tags: java, swing, jsp, nodes, jcr

I am given a Node and I then request form it another Node.

```
Node nn = node.getNode("jcr:content");
```

From here I can do the following to get the value of

```
nn.getProperty("cq:lastModified")
```

What I am trying to do is get all the properties without asking for each one by name.

```
Node nn = node.getNode("jcr:content");
PropertyIterator pi = nn.getProperties();
```

Now I can iterate over the properties and print their values as so:

```
while(pi.hasNext())
{
   Property p = pi.nextProperty();
   String val = p.getString();
}
```

But how can I find the title of this Property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you can try `getName()` method because `Property` interface is subinterface of `Item` interface. You can try like below :

```
while(pi.hasNext())
{
   Property p = pi.nextProperty();
   String name = p.getName();
   String val = p.getString();
}
```